# App asks for login if gets killed

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have an app in which I have put the option to login with facebook. After a user logs in, I store a boolean in Shared Preferences so that the next time user opens the app, he is directed to the home screen rather than login screen.

I noticed one thing, if I kill the app, it asks for login the next time I open it. Is it the default behavior of android apps or can it be fixed so that my app retains the login parameters even after it has been killed?

I am using [TinyDB](https://github.com/pipipzz/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) for storing and retrieving values from SharedPreferences.

Here is my `onCreate` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tinyDB = new TinyDB(this);
        final boolean loggedIn = tinyDB.getBoolean("Login", false);
        if(loggedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        }

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
        }

        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                startLoginOrHome(loggedIn);
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    private void startLoginOrHome(boolean loggedIn) {
        if(loggedIn) {
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your login in the `onCreate`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Yes, I do it in onCreate

Comment: Check What is the default value you get for the shared pref value

Comment: Do you have an if statement in your `onCreate`? Show me the code for the log in

Comment: Make sure that you are successfully saving Boolean variable ?

Comment: Post your code from OnCreate

Comment: @UmairKhalid I have posted the onCreate code.

Answer (score 0):

To me your problem is in saving boolean.
No need to use TinyDB just simply add following code at time of login.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
prefs.edit().putBoolean("login", true).commit();
```

and in OnCreate use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
Boolean isLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("login", false);

 Log.v(TAG,String.ValueOf(isLoggedIn)); //Use Logging to monitor  

  if(isLoggedIn) {
      goToHomeScreen()
    }
else
    goToLogInScreen()
```

Comment: I have read the code of TinyDB and I don't see any difference in what you have written and what is there in TinyDB. The effect is same. Please tell me what is wrong in my code that is causing the problem because the logic that I am using is same as to what you have written.

Comment: Use logging to monitor if issue is in retrieving isLoggedIn value. Code looks OK

Comment: Sure, would try that.